# How should I set my Future result from within a Runnable?

Tags: java, android, future

Sorry if the solution is trivial or if the question has already been asked, I am starting with Java, and I could not find an answer to this problem.

Basically, I seek a future/promise mechanism, for example like C++11 offers. It seems that Java on Android does not offer this. I return a future, where the value may be set afterward, by a listener.

Here is the code I am struggling with:

```
class SettableFutureTask extends FutureTask<Boolean> {
  public void setValue (boolean value) {
    set (new Boolean (value));
  }
}

Future<Boolean> future = new SettableFutureTask (new Runnable () {
  public void run () {
    ...
    mManager.setListener (new Listener (SettableFutureTask.this));
  }
});
return future;
```

The aim is that the listener will set the value of the future, hence `SettableFutureTask` which offers a public `setValue()`.

My problem with this code is to access the instance of `SettableFutureTask` from within the `run()` method in the `Runnable`. I also tried to rewrite some sort of Runnable and FutureTask classes to achieve this purpose, to no avail.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks,

Comment: I do not know if this is what you seek, but there exists a library called bolts that offer the same functionality as promises in javascript.

Comment: @cYrixmorten I'm not against using a third-party library, however this code is within a Cordova plugin, and I do not know how to build and import a library into my project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the instance from the run(), you could try declaring the future as final, so it's available from the scope of the method:

```
final Future<Boolean> future = new SettableFutureTask (new Runnable () {
  public void run () {
    ...
    mManager.setListener (new Listener (future));
  }
});
```

Comment: The compilation fails because the `variable future might not have been initialized`.

Comment: You are right, and I misread some part of your code.
Is there any reason for setting the listener from within the run() method, instead of after the initialization of future?
i.e.
`future = new SettableFutureTask (new ...)
...
mManager.setListener(new Listener(future));`
Maybe posting the complete code (as far as possible) might help.

Comment: While reading your comment I just realized that by code will not do what I want: the future will be completed when exiting `run()`, which may happen before the listener has a chance to set the future value... What I seek is to return a future that will block until my listener sets its value; I use `FutureTask` because it provides `set()` to manually set the value, (while `Future` does not) which implies using a `Runnable`, but if I can avoid the `run()`, I'm definitely OK with it.

Comment: Then you might want to take a look at the [java.util.concurrent.locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) package for managing the blocking.
Also [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html)

Comment: I solved my initial problem using a `ConditionVariable`, thanks to you. Way simpler that way.